# Airflow: Using MySqlHook to get connection

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm trying to get a connection object while using the MySqlHook. Assume I saved a mysql connection in the webserver admin called `test_connection`. What I've done:

```
mysql_hook = MySqlHook(conn_name_attr = 'test_connection')
conn = mysql_hook.get_conn()
```

Gives me an error: `tuple' object has no attribute 'get_conn'`

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure where that code example comes from, especially the parameter `conn_name_attr`. It seems that the parameter is wrong.

After looking [into the models](http://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/models.html?highlight=mysql) and the [hook itself](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/mysql_hook.py), it seems to be

`MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id='test_connection')`

Also, if you get back a tuple try printing it since there might be an error message or other helpful information inside it.

Comment: Just an side, I prefer to use `airflow.hooks.base_hook.BaseHook.get_connection` and then call `get_hook` against the resulting object. This future proofs your code in the event you change connection types.